# Android RecyclerView: how to add scrollToPosition(0) to Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Struggling with how to add `scrollToPosition(0)` to my `addItem()` method in my ReccylerView adapter.  To update the View, I need to have a reference to the Recyclerview?  I want a new CardView to be added to the top of my RecyclerView list and have the view show the top of the list after the new card is inserted.  Please advise.

```
Adapter.java
...
class ListContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

private List<Contact> mContacts;
private List<ListItem> mItems;

public ListContactsAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contacts) {
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mContacts = contacts;
    mItems = buildItemsList();
}

private List<ListItem> buildItemsList() {
    List<ListItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
       items.add(new ContactItem(contact));            
}

public void addItem(Contact contact) {
    if (mContacts.size()==0) {
        mItems.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    mContacts.add(contact);
    mItems.add(new ContactItem(contact));
    notifyItemInserted(0);
}
```

Here is Activity code for adding the item:

```
...
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Contact contact = new Contact("", "");
            mContactsAdapter.addItem(contact);
            // need to figure out scrollToPosition(0) here
        }
    });
```

If I use recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0); Android Studio reports the following error:  "Variable 'recyclerView' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RecyclerView` has two methods `scrollToPosition` and `smoothScrollToPosition`, you can use these methods to show the top of the list after `notifyItemInserted()`

---

Declare the recyclerview as the member variable of Activity, not the local variable in method, just like `mContactsAdapter`.

Sample Code:

```
public class XXXActivity extends Activity{
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    // ....

    public void initViews(){
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.xxx);
        // ....
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Contact contact = new Contact("", "");
                mContactsAdapter.addItem(contact);
                mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
            }
        });
    }
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know the method I want to use.  I'm not sure how to reference the RecyclerView which is in the Activity file from the Adapter file that has the addItem code in it.

Comment: Now adapter's `addItem(Contact contact)` is invoked in activity file, right? You just need  to write  `RecyclerView`'s  `scrollToPosition ()` after `addItem(Contact contact)`.

Comment: Or you pass the `RecyclerView` instance through adapter's constructor, then write `scrollToPosition()` in adapter's `addItem(Contact contact)`

Comment: No it's not invoked in the activity file.  That's what I'm asking how to do.

Comment: So where is the `addItem(Contact contact)` invoked?

Comment: It's not because that is the code I'm trying to add but not sure how to do.

Comment: Nicely done, works well.  Still have a few tweaks but should be good now.  Answer accepted and upvoted.  Cheers.